# Access or recover files from Apple hdd with bad S.M.A.R.T. and 05-reallocating sector bad

Tags: hard-disk, badblocks, smart, apple

I have a Macintosh HD (hfsPlus)

```
[/dev/sdc2 on /media/ubuntu/Macintosh HD type hfsplus(ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)]
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted. 

Disk /dev/sdc: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  1465149167   732574583+  ee  GPT Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Diagnostic software tells me that the S.M.A.R.T. status is bad and also that the 05-reallocating sector count is bad.

I'm trying to recover some data from it without having to spend $600 to ship it to a company that does the manual recover. I don't care about the disk, it's still under warranty.  I tried to go to mac doctor but they couldn't get anything out (I think they just tried mounted it on a mac and runitf MacDrive.)

I've tried with Windows 7 and I managed to mount the drive but some software was not seeing it and the only one who did it was too slow and kind of *crappy*.
I'm trying now with Ubuntu in a bootable flashdrive but I cannot open the media because of input/output errors while reading the `.journal` file.

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc2 at /media/ubuntu/Macintosh HD: Command-line mount -t "hfsplus"
-o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdc2" "/media/ubuntu/Macintosh HD"' exited with
on-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
/dev/sdc2,missing codepage or helper program, or other error.In some cases useful info
is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so
```

I'd love it if someone could point me in the right direction; I have some fundamental knowledge on computers but I'm not a developer.

Comment: You should include the exact input/output errors you see when mounting the drive with Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I m very fresh on ubuntu, I m trying to do that by using:
`sudo mkdir /media/testFolder
sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/testFolder`
this is what i get `/dev/sdc already mounted or /media/testFolder busy`

trying to umount with the similar code but it-s not working.

Comment: and this is what I get when I try to do it manually without the terminal:
`Error mounting /dev/sdc2 at /media/ubuntu/Macintosh HD: Command-line `mount -t "hfsplus" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdc2" "/media/ubuntu/Macintosh HD"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2,missing codepage or helper program, or other error.In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail  or so`

Comment: I don't know the solution to your problem, but it will help others if you edit your post with the info you provided.  It's harder to read and understand when it's in the comments.

Comment: thanks drs for the heads up, and for the editing I appreciate it. My apologize for my bad english. :P

Answer (score 1):

First, do not use fdisk with GPT.

Second, since the disk is indeed failing and considering that you have ample free disk space the best thing you can do is clone the entire disk to an image and then work on that image without caring about the disk. You can do this with `dd if=/dev/sdc of=image_of_disk.img`, assuming that the failing disk is /dev/sdc and it is really mildly defect.

However, if the data are quite important it is better to use tools like `ddrescue`. More information [here](http://www.technibble.com/forums/showthread.php?t=48269) [and](http://techmuck.blogspot.nl/2012/03/data-recovery-with-gnu-ddrescue.html) [here](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue). Be careful, though because it may take a long time ([even days](https://superuser.com/questions/413650/is-there-any-way-to-speed-up-ddrescue), depending mainly on the number of failed blocks) before the full image is done. This step apparently requires that you have free space as much as the whole failed disk. Also, be careful on the arguments you use with `ddrescue`, since you want to clone to an image file and not the whole drive. Given the [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637294/ddrescuegnu-algorithm) [arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) you should first try to fast read the readable portions of the disk and then, on a second-third phase insist on the bad blocks.

Then, you can work on the completed image with tools like [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

The point in failing disks is that if they have, e.g. only a few hours left till complete death, it's better to devote those hours on making an image, since futile attempts to mount them will just lead them to death earlier.

I think what the above links (and their "cousin" software projects) provide are the best a simple user can do with software and I would not mess with the hardware, unless it's evident there is a problem with the electric circuit/PCB. For the rest of the hardware problems I would send it to a specialized company, since the risk of permanently damaging the data is super-high, and the cost for the simple users to buy the tools does not worth it. Nevertheless, I would like to do a [head replacement or platter swap](http://www.pinterest.com/dolphindatalab/hard-drive-head-replacement-platter-swap-tool-kits/) some time in my life. :)

Comment: Thanks 2383408, I'll try to create the image tonight, using and researching the tools you mentioned.